# RegEx for extracting tag attributes

Tags: javascript, regex

Say, I have a string like

```
<body class="body-element" style="background: red;"><div class="inner">...</div></body>
```

I would like to extract all attributes of body tag. As for jQuery parsing ignores body tag I can't use it. So, how to do it using regular expressions?

I need to extract attributes only from the body tag.

Comment: Consider `document.querySelector('body').attributes` instead.

Comment: @Walk is this solution cross-platform? And I don't have any document object, it's just a string.

Comment: It is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes#Browser_compatibility

Comment: In that case you can parse it first: `(new DOMParser()).parseFromString('<body class="body-element" style="background: red;"></body>', 'application/xml').querySelector('body').attributes`. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Answer (score 3):

Use a `DOMParser`, get the `.body` and then its `.attributes`.

```js
var s = '<body class="body-element" style="background: red;"><div>...</div></body>';

var attrs = new DOMParser().parseFromString(s, "text/html").body.attributes;

for (const a of attrs) console.log("%s = %s", a.name, a.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/Bo9Bvu/1) might help you to divide your input HTML string into two groups and get the desired attributes:

```
([a-z]+)="([A-Za-z0-9_\-\:\s;]+)
```

You might add other chars to `[A-Za-z0-9_\-\:\s;]`, if necessary.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I need to extract attributes only from body tag. This regex will catch all of them.